# Is there a galactic main sequence?

Tags: galaxy, stellar-evolution, main-sequence, hr-diagram, galactic-evolution

Stars can be plotted on an HR diagram, on which a main sequence is apparent, and stellar evolution can be plotted on on such a diagram as a function of mass. Is there an analog for galactic evolution? Are there "main sequence galaxies"?

Comment: For you, what would qualify as a "main sequence" - that is, what properties would a "main sequence galaxy" have? The term has been applied to galaxies with a particular relation between star formation rate and stellar mass, and I'd written an answer noting that, but I'm not entirely sure that it's what you're looking for.

Comment: [Early-type galaxies obey a narrow relation traced by their stellar content between the mass and size (Mass- Radius relation).](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=early+galaxies+mass+radius)